# Bessel functions in terms of the confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: summation, special-functions, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function, summation-method

I am familiar with the representation of the Bessel functions as

$$J_m(x) = \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (k + m)!} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k},$$

for some integer $m$.

Now, I have come across the representation of the Bessel functions in terms of the confluent hypergeometric function as

$$J_m(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(m + 1)} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m e^{-i x} \Phi\left(m + \frac{1}{2}, 2m + 1; 2i x\right).\tag{*}$$

I would like to show that these two are equivalent.

We know that

$$\Phi(\alpha, \gamma; x) = \frac{\Gamma(\gamma)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(k + \alpha)}{\Gamma(k + \gamma) \Gamma(k + 1)} x^k.$$

Thus, $J_m(x)$ in terms of the confluent hypergeometric function is:

$$J_m(x) = \frac{1}{m!} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m e^{-i x} \frac{\Gamma(2m + 1)}{\Gamma(m + \frac{1}{2})} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(k + m + \frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(k + 2m + 1) \Gamma(k + 1)} (2i x)^k.$$

By exploiting the following two relations

\begin{align*}
\Gamma(n + 1) &= n!,
\\
\Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right) &= \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} n!} \sqrt{\pi},
\end{align*}

the above reduces to

$$J_m(x) = \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m e^{-i x} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k + 2m)!}{2^{2k} (k + 2m)! (k + m)! k!} (2i x)^k.$$

From here, I don't know how one could go further, for example, how to get rid of the exponential term and etc., and to reproduce the representation of the Bessel functions as given in the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may deduce $(\text{*})$ from the [Poisson's integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9#E4) for $\Re m>-1/2$, $$J_m(x)=\frac{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^m}{\Gamma\left(m+\frac12\right)\sqrt\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}(1-t^2)^{m-1/2}e^{ixt}\,dt,\tag{1}\label{poisson}$$ for a proof, expand $e^{ixt}$ into a power series and integrate termwise, and [the one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations) for $$\Phi(\alpha;\gamma;x)=\frac{\Gamma(\gamma)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\gamma-\alpha)}\int_0^1 z^{\alpha-1}(1-z)^{\gamma-\alpha-1}e^{xz}\,dz \qquad(\Re\gamma>\Re\alpha>0),$$ obtained the same way. The RHS of $(\text{*})$ is then $$\frac{(x/2)^m e^{-ix}}{\Gamma(m+1)}\frac{\Gamma(2m+1)}{\Gamma^2(m+1/2)}\int_0^1\big(z(1-z)\big)^{m-1/2}e^{2ixz}\,dz.$$ Using the [duplication formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5#E5) for $\Gamma(2m+1)$ and substituting $z=(1+t)/2$, we get the RHS of \eqref{poisson}.